# Bundle react in some JS file instead of (Bundling and Adding) in HTML file (dev mode)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Im doing React project. Process of react is bundle all files and inject in `public/index.html` file. This process is like "`watch`" activity.

I want same process but only bundling JS file in `public` folder. like watch only JS file when changed/update. so I can link that JS file in any file I want. 

By this approach I can use that JS file in any framework/technology like php,asp etc.

I guess `webpack` can do that but I don't know how, other possible solution are OK if they work.

Comment: can you rephrase your question or tell us why you want to do this. Right now it's not very clear

Comment: I dont know what react do in the backend when I do "npm start" in react project.
but apparently I can see react makes changes in JS file and inject in my index.html.
I want to do same but I dont want to inject it in index.html... I want to just create bundle in JS file and place in some folder.